# using the same function but on different rows

Tags: matlab, function, covariance

I want to estimate the co(variance) matrix of two assets classes (with different derivatives) of every month.. So let's assume that each month is 25 days. I will get the following code,

```
covar=cov([elec(1:25,:) ngas(1:25,:)])
```

However, I have like 5 years of data so rewrite everything seems like a waste of time, and I think there has to be an easier way to fix this problem.

ps. I do think the answer to my question is already answered somewhere, but I do not know the words the search on. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Note that if you don't have exactly 25 days per month, you would need to use some kind of indication which days belong to which month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a `for` loop?

```
counter = 0;
cover{floor(size(elec,1)/25)} = [];  %//Pre-allocation
for day = 1:25:size(elec,1)
    counter = counter + 1;
    covar{counter}=cov([elec(day:day+25-1,:) ngas(day:day+25-1,:)])
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this exactly what I needed.. Only one problem occurred, when I run the code this error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" shows up. First thoughts, may be I should adjust the matrix size of elec ngas so that the rows matches the table of 25.. Unfortunately the was not the solution. Second thoughts, may be this error is normal because I get all the co-variance matrices that I needed.. @Dan thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @user45266  See my edit, I think I should have been going from `day` to `day+25-1` instead of adding the full 25, otherwise you actually have 26 samples each step. Try that.

Comment: Thank you Dan and Dennis